# Socket.io java client get same message more than one time

Tags: java, android, socket.io, client

I am using **socket.io** on my android chat application. In order to keep connection alive, I am connecting socket in a service which is started in main activity. And I check if socket is connected. If it is not, I make socket connection. Here is my codes:

```
try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.x.x:XXXX");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if(!mSocket.connected()){   
        mSocket.connect();
    }

    mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
    mSocket.on("user joined", onUserJoined);
    mSocket.emit("add user", "MobileUser");

    message += cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    sendMessage();

public void sendMessage(){
     mSocket.emit("new message", message);
     addMessage("MobileUser", message);
}
```

Connections works perfectly. My service sends message using socket in every minute. This seems like this in an other client:

```
MobileUser: 1:11
MobileUser: 1:12
MobileUser: 1:13
MobileUser: 1:14
MobileUser: 1:15
```

**Here is my problem:** After these 5 messages  ( 5 times is just an example, it could be any number more than 1), if an other client sends message, I get this message for 5 times. But of course I want to get this message for once. How can I handle with this problem? Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

My onNewMessage Method is on client side:

```
private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
public void call(final Object... args) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            try {
                username = data.getString("username");
                message = data.getString("message");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return;
            }

            Log.v(username, message);
        }
    });

    t.start();
  }
};
```

And the "new message" event on my server:

```
socket.on('new message', function (data) {
   console.log('message: ' + data);

   socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
   });
});
```

Comment: What are you doing in your onNewMessage Method ? It seems you are listening to and emiting the "new message" Event in your server which might be the problem

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm going to edit my question with adding onNewMessage method. @risuch

Comment: So far nothing looks faulty, but its not fully clear what all parts are involved in your client- server app, so its hard to elaborate. You might want to upload some plunker or so that full information is visible. It also seems that your server is node.js and Client Java, right ?, and all Clients use the same code and connect to the same server ?

Comment: Yes, my server is node.js. Actually when I used this project ( https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat.git)  as a client, I don't get this problem. But I want to use socket.io in a service in order to keep alive the connection, as I mentioned before. @risuch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I should check if socket is connected or not in my service class but these codes shouldn't be in there:

```
mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
mSocket.on("user joined", onUserJoined);
mSocket.emit("add user", "MobileUser");
```

I removed these from my service class and put the MainActivity class. Problem is solved.